# python import statements underlined in yellow, in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, package

i want to code with numpy and cv2 package in VSC.

I import it with

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

but it has a yellow lines under it.

I tried to `pip3 install numpy` in the terminal and in the cmd.

I tried to create venv in my working directory but i wasn't able to switch.

I watched 1000000 youtube videos, but after doing exactly what they did in the videos, it's still the same problem.

Anyone knows what else could be the problem?

Comment: browse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+import+python -- i've removed the numpy and opencv tags since this is not specific to those packages. your issue is how to configure VSC.

Comment: Please describe in detail what the yellow line is. Is the module not installed or unused？